# Flutter logical decission between Video and Image in UI

Tags: list, image, user-interface, flutter, video

I'm a little bit lost in an App I'm trying to write. I'd like to display either an image, or an Video - depending on an entry in a list.

So, if the entry in the list I'm currently displaying has a video I want to use the Chewie Player in the UI

```
child = Chewie(
       controller: _chewieController,
)
```

if the entry in the list I'm currently displaying has an image I want to use CachedNetworkImage:

```
CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: _questions[widget.questionno].getSourceUrl(),)
```

as you probably noticed, I am a programming beginner. How can I solve this problem?

Right now the code I'm trying to use in the UI looks like this:

```
Container(
  if (_questions[widget.questionno].getVideo()=="Ja") {
    child = Chewie(
           controller: _chewieController,
    )
  } else {
    child = CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: _questions[widget.questionno].getSourceUrl(),)
  }

),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
bool video = false

if(entryInList is Video){ //Replace Video with whatever type you would have 
                          //for Videos
  video = true
}
```

And in your Widget tree

```
child: video ? VideoWidget() : FotoWidget()
```

Or all in one line:

```
child: entryInList is Video ? VideoWidget() : FotoWidget()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Unfortunately I do not know how to implent your idea.  Isn't my code above going in a similar direction? (I guess your one liner in the end is just short version and also needs an if else?). With my above code I get the error that I am missing an identifier and a ")"...

Answer (score 0):

finally got it working, it's probably not the best way, but whatever, it works and I'm super happy :D

```
child: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      if (_questions[widget.questionno].getVideo()=='Ja') {
        return 
        Container(child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController,));
      } else {
        return 
        Container(child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: _questions[widget.questionno].getSourceUrl(),));
      }
    }
  )
```

additionally I also had to put the whole definition of the chewie controller (which is in initState) into an if thingie.